# How do I move tables' rows to production server database

Tags: migration

I've been developing a Django project on my machine, and I'm ready to push it to the web. I set up the project on a remote server, then ran `manage.py migrate` to get the tables set up. But the server's tables are empty. I'd like to move the rows from my local database's tables to those on the remote server. In both cases, I use Postgres. Is there a Django way to do this? Or do I need to do this some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) or the  [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal.